# Width of <select> list in windows wider than mac

Tags: html, css, windows, macos, google-chrome

When I have a wide select list, its width on Chrome(or any other browser) is wider on Windows OS when compared to mac. Is there an easy way to achieve consistent width?

For example, if you open http://jsfiddle.net/8Rxsc/5/ on windows and mac, the width of the select box in windows is 295px while on mac it is 278px.

```
<body>
    <select>
        <option selected>Select One</option>
    <option>One </option>
    <option>Two Two</option>
    <option>Three Three Three </option>
    <option>Four Four Four Four </option>
    <option>Five Five Five Five Five </option>
    <option>Six Six Six Six Six Six </option>
    <option>Seven Seven Seven Seven Seven Seven Seven</option>
    <option>Eight Eight Eight Eight Eight Eight Eight Eight </option>
    <option>Nine Nine Nine Nine Nine Nine Nine Nine Nine </option>
    <option>Ten Ten Ten Ten Ten Ten Ten Ten Ten Ten </option>
    </select>
</body>
```

[image: Chrome browser On Windows]

[image: Chrome browser on mac]

Answer (score 0):

Consistent width is added by telling the right element what `width` you want it to be, say for example:

```
select {
  width: 800px;
}
```

Your fiddle updated: http://jsfiddle.net/8Rxsc/3/

Answer (score 0):

You can set the width of the select box using css that way it will always be the same on all browsers.

```
select {width:295px;}
```

Comment: Thanks @DD0UG ... width and max-width were the 2 attributes I looked at; however, the issue with this is that if we have longer options, they will be truncated when selected. I am looking for a solution where the width is the same across operating systems without having to restrict the size.